# i3 window manager: ampersand (&) in commands

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, i3-window-manager

I've started using i3, and set up some keysyms to rename a workspace, like it says in the docs:

```
bindsym $mod+r i3-input -F 'rename workspace to "%s"' -P 'New name: '
```

Now I noticed that not all inputs are accepted: If I enter a workspace name like "Mail&News", the workspace gets renamed to an empty string instead.

I didn't find a workaround for this yet - could this be a bug?

Comment: Checking the output of `i3-msg -t get_workspaces` it looks like the workspace is actually renamed to "Mail&News" but *i3bar* is unable to display the name correctly.  This also happens when creating a new workspace with the i3 command `workspace "Mail&News"`. This is most definitely a bug. You may want to post a bug report on [i3's bug tracker](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues).

Comment: I created a bug report at https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is the result of the [bug report](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1941) I posted. Thanks Airblader for the quick response.)

You probably have set `font` in your *i3* configuration to use Pango. For example:

```
font "pango:SomeFont 12"
```

From the [i3 User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_changing_named_workspaces_moving_to_workspaces):

> Workspace names are parsed as [Pango markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) by i3bar.

Pango markup is based on XML as such characters like `&` and `<` have special meaning because they are part of the XML syntax.

If you want to have `&` or `<` in your workspace name, you have to escape them and write `&amp;` or `&lt;` instead:

```
rename workspace to "Mail&amp;News"
rename workspace to "ten&lt;eleven"
```

Of course this is rather unwieldy when renaming utilizing `i3-input`. You could use `dmenu` for a more user-friendly method.

Save the following script as `workspace-renamer.sh` and make it executable:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -

# get name from dmenu. 
$wsname=$(echo -n | dmenu)
# escape backslashes to avoid inadvertently escaping other characters
wsname=${wsname//\\/\\\\}
# escape double quotes as the name is passed inside double quotes to i3-msg
wsname=${wsname//\"/\\\"}
# escape ampersand because of pango
wsname=${wsname//&/&amp;}
# escape less-than sign also because of pango
wsname=${wsname//</&lt;}

# call i3-msg to rename workspace
i3-msg rename workspace to "\"${wsname}\""
```

Then add this to your *i3* configuration:

```
bindsym $mod+r exec --no-startup-id /path/to/workspace-renamer.sh
```

This automatically escapes `\`, `"`, `&` and `<`, so that the name you type in is then shown in the i3bar. This is of course only a quick prototype and be further improved. You could for example replace `echo -n` with something that provides a newline separated list of choices as preset.